# How to get server name without using Host header from http request

Tags: scala, security, playframework

In my Play 2.5.x (Scala) web application I am using following technique to get absolute URL of the route (server name + uri):

```
controllers.routes.MyController.MyRoute.absoluteURL()
```

I recently found out that it uses Host header in the incoming http request to return absolute url. Use of Host header is not recommended as it's quite easy to do Host header injection attack.
Is there a secure way of getting the server name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Play! implementation of [CSRF](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCsrf) attack protection and the [Allowed Hosts](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AllowedHostsFilter) configuration.

You can specify known hosts with the latter and it will reject requests from unknown hosts.